# NiFi processors don't react

Tags: apache-nifi

I can't start or stop 2 processors: PutHiveQL and ListHDFS after I had to restart NiFi because of memory overload. Other processors react fine.
Even after 4 hours the processors don't react. I tried stopping the processors by stopping the Process Group but it failed.

Comment: Was anything suspicious printed out in the `nifi-app.log`? And which version of NiFi are you using? With NiFi 1.6.0+, you can terminate non responding processors.

Comment: Not that I could find. I am using NiFi 1.4.0. Problem is solved now, but I did not do anything. Guess I had to wait some more?

Comment: Hive 1.2 doesn't have a client side query timeout, so in NiFi I think you just have to wait for it to finish, or try to sever the connection from the Hive side.

Answer (score 0):

Check the nifi-app.log file, you can also make a tail -f to the file to see what's going on in real time.

Also check this values in the processors:

- Concurrent tasks.
- Run schedule.
- Run duration.

The default configuration is not so good and can give problems.